# Oracle PL/SQL - Heterogeneous iterable data structure

Tags: arrays, oracle, data-structures, plsql, iterable

I'm looking for a way to define a data structure in Oracle PL/SQL with heterogeneous data and where I'm able to iterate the values.

I don't know if it's possible as for what I have seen the data structures like arrays and associative arrays only allow all elements to be of the same type.

My use case is that I receive a bunch of values and have to process them and insert them in a table.

I would like to have something like this:

```sql
DECLARE
   type books is record
      (title varchar(50)   := myvar1,
      author varchar(50)   := myvar2,
      subject varchar(100) := myvar3,
      book_id number       := myvar4);
BEGIN
  FOR item IN ('SELECT * FROM books')
  LOOP
    /* Here I would access each individual item key and value (title, author...) */
    my_function(item.key, item.value)
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Note that in the example above I want to iterate the fields, not records, there's a single record.

So I want something very similar to an object in Javascript:

```js
var obj = {
  title: 'Romeo and Juliet',
  author: 'Some dude',
  subject: 'Romance',
  book_id: 332764
};
    
for (const prop in obj) {
  console.log(`obj.${prop} = ${obj[prop]}`);
}
```

This is for Oracle 19c.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow exactly what you want to do.  You could use `dbms_sql` to execute a dynamic query, describe the results to find out the columns and data types, and then iterate through that.  But it isn't obvious to me from your question that you need something of this level of complexity.  In your loop, you can simply reference `item.title` and `item.author` (assuming `title` and `author` are columns in a `books` table).  If you create a local variable of type `books`, you can similarly refer to `variable.title` and `variable.author`.

Comment: @JustinCave If I have to use `item.title`, `item.author`... I would have to repeat the same thing like 20 times. Having 20 different lines with an `INSERT` statement looks ugly, I want DRY code. Also, in the future, if I want another item to insert I just need to add it to the structure and done.

Comment: But you're saying that you need to process the values and insert them into a table.  Depending on where the values are coming from and what that processing looks like, you may be looking for dynamic SQL.  You may be able to do a simple `execute immediate` or you may need to use `dbms_sql`.  That wouldn't involve a PL/SQL record, though, I'm not sure if that's a requirement.

Comment: @JustinCave I see, so it seems there's no simple way to do it in PL/SQL :/
I really was expecting that there would be an easy way.

Comment: SQL and PL/SQL are strongly data-typed, with a rigid adherence to data structures. That's because data integrity is the prime directive. Yes that makes a bit more work for developers when it comes to inserting data into a table. But it also means there's less work for developers when it comes to retrieving the data. And most importantly it means our users can rely on the stability and correctness of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following. At the schema level create a Books object with the attributes defined and then create a collection of that object.

```
create type books as object
      (title   varchar(50)    
      ,author  varchar(50)   
      ,subject varchar(100) 
      ,book_id number 
      );
  
create type table_of_books as 
    table of books;
```

You can then process the table as any other collections but qualifying the items within via standard dot (.) referencing. See [Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f364e73ae32d0ea77e92dd61077abaeb).

If you need the defaults you have defined then create a [constructor](https://www.guru99.com/object-types-pl-sql.html#2) for your object definition.

---

Revised for Local Definition

```
declare
   type books is record
        (title   varchar(50)    
        ,author  varchar(50)   
        ,subject varchar(100) 
        ,book_id number 
        );      
   type table_of_books is 
      table of books;
   list_of_books table_of_books;    
begin
  dbms_output.enable;
  list_of_books := table_of_books(); -- initialize collection
  -- populates List
  list_of_books.extend(2);
  list_of_books(1) := books('First Book','Me','Simple ones',12345);
  list_of_books(2) := books('Another First','You','Advnnced ones',94321);  
  
   -- processing 

  dbms_output.put_line('Current List of ' || list_of_books.count || ' books');
  for item in 1 .. list_of_books.count  
  loop 
    /* Here I would access each individual item (title, author...) */
    dbms_output.put_line( 'ID: ' || list_of_books(item).book_id 
                        || ', Title: '  || list_of_books(item).title
                        || ', By: ' || list_of_books(item).author
                        ); 
                       
  end loop;
end;
```

---

**Why NOT to use local definition.**

You asked it you could create but not be visible everywhere. Yes you can, but why. You create objects so that you do not need to create them every time they are needed.

Further if define locally in 2 procedures they are NOT the same definition therefore cannot be passed as a parameter. When created locally the definitions cannot be used in SQL.  
But objects, like most things in Oracle have [privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/privileges-on-object-types-and-their-methods.html#GUID-73B9AFB8-FE49-4177-AC8B-3C74000943F8) you can use them to control access (or deny access). Another option would be to wrap the definitions along with procedures and/of functions processing them into a package. The control control visibility by accessibility to the package.

Comment: I like this. But is there a way not to create a type that will be visible everywhere? Like how we can create nested subprograms.

Comment: Yes you can, but WHY? The idea of of creating at the schema is so you do not have to define it every time you need it. But I updated the answer to show a local version and some reasoning why NOT to do so.

Comment: This is not really what I need, but is close. I need to iterate the fields, not the records. I will have a single record. I need to iterate the fields getting the field name and the value associated to it. This way it would work like an associative array with heterogeneous data.